# Unable to scrape names from the second page of a webpage when the url remains unchanged

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape different agency name from the second page of a [webpage](https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/opportunity/BOListing.xhtml?origin=menu) using requests module. I can parse the names from it's landing page by sending a get requests to the very url.

However, when it comes to access the names from it's second page and latter, I need to send post http requests along with appropriate parameters. I tried to mimic the post requests exactly the way I see it in dev tools but all I get in return is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><redirect url="/ptn/exceptionhandler/sessionExpired.xhtml"></redirect></partial-response>
```

This is how I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/opportunity/BOListing.xhtml?origin=menu'
url = 'https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/opportunity/BOListing.xhtml'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    payload = {
        'contentForm': 'contentForm',
        'contentForm:j_idt171_windowName': '',
        'contentForm:j_idt187_listButton2_HIDDEN-INPUT': '',
        'contentForm:j_idt192_searchBar_INPUT-SEARCH': '',
        'contentForm:j_idt192_searchBarList_HIDDEN-SUBMITTED-VALUE': '',
        'contentForm:j_id135_0': 'Title',
        'contentForm:j_id135_1': 'Document No.',
        'contentForm:j_id136': 'Match All',
        'contentForm:j_idt853_select': 'ON',
        'contentForm:j_idt859_select': '0',
        'javax.faces.ViewState': soup.select_one('input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]')['value'],
        'javax.faces.source': 'contentForm:j_idt902:j_idt955_2_2',
        'javax.faces.partial.event': 'click',
        'javax.faces.partial.execute': 'contentForm:j_idt902:j_idt955_2_2 contentForm:j_idt902',
        'javax.faces.partial.render': 'contentForm:j_idt902:j_idt955 contentForm dialogForm',
        'javax.faces.behavior.event': 'action',
        'javax.faces.partial.ajax': 'true'
    }

    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/opportunity/BOListing.xhtml?origin=menu'
    s.headers['Faces-Request'] = 'partial/ajax'
    s.headers['Origin'] = 'https://www.gebiz.gov.sg'
    s.headers['Host'] = 'www.gebiz.gov.sg'
    s.headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate, br'

    res = s.post(url,data=payload,allow_redirects=False)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    # for item in soup.select(".commandLink_TITLE-BLUE"):
    #     print(item.get_text(strip=True))
    print(res.text)
```

> How can I parse names from a webpage from it's second page when the url remains unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium to traverse between pages. The following code will allow you to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.gebiz.gov.sg/ptn/opportunity/BOListing.xhtml?origin=menu")

#check if next page exists
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@value, 'Next')]")

#click the next button
while next_page is not None:
    time.sleep(5)
    click_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@value, 'Next')]")
    click_btn.click()
    time.sleep(5)
    next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@value, 'Next')]")
```

I have not added the code for extracting the Agency names. I presume it will not be difficult for you.

Make sure to install Selenium and download the [chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Also make sure to download the correct version of the driver. You can confirm the version by viewing the 'About' section of your chrome browser.